# NullPointerException in actionPerformed method but not in main?

Tags: java

```
    public class DictionaryClient implements ActionListener {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Amazing CW");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      JButton button = new JButton("Send");
      JTextField  text = new JTextField("Field");
      Book book;
      DictionaryService port;

    public DictionaryClient() {

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(text);
    frame.add(panel);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    DictionaryClient client = new DictionaryClient();
    DictionaryServiceService service = new DictionaryServiceService();
    DictionaryService port = service.getDictionaryServicePort();

    Book book = port.sendBook();

}

    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(e.getSource() == button){
                  System.out.print(book.getAuthor() + " " + book.getTitle());
               }
        }
}
```

I understand what a NullPointerException is but don't understand by my code is giving me this error, when I move the

```
System.out.print(book.getAuthor() + " " + book.getTitle());
```

out of the actionPerformed I get no issue at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Book book = port.sendBook();
```

Creates a local variable named `book`. It does not affect the field `book` in your `DictionaryClient` class, which keeps its default value of `null`. Change it to this:

```
client.book = port.sendBook();
```

That will assign the value to the correct field on your `DictionaryClient` object.

As it is now, that value is lost as soon as the main method ends and the local variable goes out of scope. When you moved the `print` into the main method, it was able to reference the local variable but, in your `actionPerformed` method the only `book` in scope was the field, which was never initialized.

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your Book object only has local scope in the main method. You need to change its scope to be local to the class (which you've already referenced).

Simply change this line

```
Book book = port.sendBook();
```

to

```
client.book = port.sendBook();
```

This will set the class level book variable correctly. Your actionPerformed method will then refer to that instance variable accordingly.

Comment: Since `main` is static, they'll also need to use a reference to a `DictionaryClient` to access `book`.

Comment: Yes, very true. Thanks. Your answer is the better one :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
the following declaration/initialization

```
Book book = port.sendBook();
```

was made inside of the static main method, and since your class **DictionaryClient**  has a member with the same name, then this object in the main method is ***shadowing*** the book of the DictionaryClient, when the `actionPerformed` is triggered, **you are not in the static main anymore**, so you **book** defined and well initialized there is back for good...
the only book available in that scope is the defined in the class...

but is was never initialized therefore a NPE.